# Order posts latest on top php sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want my latest post to be on top of other posts, how can i accomplish this? Now it just posts the latest at the bottom of the one i posted before.

I use this simple code to display my posts:

```
                    <div class="container">

                        <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="boximg"> </div>

                            <div class="z link">
                                <a  href="article.php?id=<?php echo  $article['article_id'] ;   ?>">
                                    <?php echo $article['article_title']; ?>

                                </a>-
                                <small> posted
        <?php echo date('l jS', $article['article_timestamp']); ?>


        </small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>


                        <br>
                    </div>
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: question is incomplete as it is.. MySQL table structure with some example data is missing. Also the PHP code is missing where you retrive the data from MySQL and build up the $articles array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fetching the articles like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles 
ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC;
```

See [MySQL ORDER BY: Sort a Result Set](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) for insight.